# Is there a way to explode a string using a 'pattern'

Tags: python, list

I have a string :

```
mystring = "Foo: Bar (Titi) Foo-age: 50 Airplanes: 12:1 12:3 12:4 12:5 [...] Next Hop: LAX Origine ID: 49 Hop List 2 4 9 0 3 [...]"
```

Is there a way to split this string using a pattern, like:

```
pattern = {"Foo", "Foo-age", "Airplanes", "Next Hop", "Origine ID", "Hop List"}
```

and then

```
mylist = somefunction(mystring , pattern)
print mylist 
--> {"Foo":"Bar (Titi)","Foo-age" : 50, "Airplanes": ["12:1","12:3",...], ...}
```

Is that possible in python?

**[EDIT]**

Some sample data - a 5-col csv file w/ delimiter ","

```
col-1,col-2,Path: 9876 (IGP) Local-Pref: 310000   MED: 0 Communities: 1234:6 1234:95 1234:101 1234:202 1234:500 1234:903 1234:3369 1234:8000 1234:8002 1234:16925 9876:19827 Next Hop: x.x.127.151   Originator ID: x.x.155.144 Cluster List: 0.0.29.99 0.0.29.97 0.0.26.245 0.0.2.179 ,col-4,col-5

col-1,col-2,Path: 9876 (IGP) Local-Pref: 310000   MED: 0 Communities: 1234:3 1234:95 1234:101 1234:202 1234:13705 9876:19941 Next Hop: x.x.127.61   Originator ID: x.x.137.37 Cluster List: 0.0.29.99 0.0.29.97 0.0.1.195 ,col-4,col-5

col-1,col-2,Path: 9876 (IGP) Local-Pref: 310000   MED: 0 Communities: 1234:2 1234:95 1234:101 Next Hop: x.x.127.149   Originator ID: x.x.137.29 Cluster List: 0.0.29.99 0.0.29.98 0.0.2.240 ,col-4,col-5

col-1,col-2,Path: 9876 (IGP) Local-Pref: 310000   MED: 0 Communities: 1234:6 1234:95 1234:101 1234:202 1234:500 1234:903 1234:3369 1234:8000 1234:8002 1234:16924 9876:19827 Next Hop: x.x.127.151   Originator ID: x.x.155.144 Cluster List: 0.0.29.99 0.0.29.97 0.0.26.245 0.0.2.179 ,col-4,col-5
```

Comment: I can use regex, but my string has not exactly the same formatting on each line (it comes from a """csv""" file)

Comment: if regex wont do it then it's doubtful you can do it in one line. Perhaps you should explain the problem more clearly since regex can ignore things like linebreaks when required. Show some more sample data that's giving you trouble.

Comment: I believe that a solution based on the csv file directly might be easier. Could you add an example to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done in two steps. First, you look for something that looks like a field name (`Foo-Bar:`) and insert a "special" marker character (e.g. `@`) before each match. Second, you look for the pattern `marker field-name : data` and populate the data dictionary:

```
text = """
col-1,col-2,Path: 9876 (IGP) Local-Pref: 310000   MED: 0 Communities: 1234:6 1234:95 1234:101 1234:202 1234:500 1234:903 1234:3369 1234:8000 1234:8002 1234:16925 9876:19827 Next Hop: x.x.127.151   Originator ID: x.x.155.144 Cluster List: 0.0.29.99 0.0.29.97 0.0.26.245 0.0.2.179 ,col-4,col-5
"""

import re

text = re.sub(r'([A-Z][A-Za-z -]+:)', r'@\1', text)
data = {}
for m in re.finditer(r'@(.+?):([^,@]+)', text):
    data[m.group(1)] = m.group(2).strip()

import pprint
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Result:

```
 {'Cluster List': '0.0.29.99 0.0.29.97 0.0.26.245 0.0.2.179',
  'Communities': '1234:6 1234:95 1234:101 1234:202 1234:500 1234:903 1234:3369 1234:8000 1234:8002 1234:16925 9876:19827',
  'Local-Pref': '310000',
  'MED': '0',
  'Next Hop': 'x.x.127.151',
  'Originator ID': 'x.x.155.144',
  'Path': '9876 (IGP)'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one might be a bit tricky.

Please specify more, but for now this solution should either suffice or get you closer to what you desire:

```
mystring = "Foo: Bar (Titi) Foo-age: 50 Airplanes: 12:1 12:3 12:4 12:5 Next Hop: LAX Origine ID: 49 Hop List: 2 4 9 0 3"
pattern = {"Foo", "Foo-age", "Airplanes", "Next Hop", "Origine ID", "Hop List"}
to_list = {'Airplanes', 'Hop List'}
def obtain_data(mystring, pattern, to_list):    
    result = {}
    prev_pattern = None
    prev_pos = 0
    ordered_pattern = sorted(list(pattern), key=lambda x: mystring.find(x + ':'))
    for p in ordered_pattern:
        npos = mystring.find(p +':', prev_pos)
        if prev_pattern is not None:
            to_add = mystring[prev_pos+len(prev_pattern)+1 : npos].strip()
            if prev_pattern in to_list:
                to_add = to_add.split()
            result[prev_pattern] = to_add
        prev_pos = npos
        prev_pattern = p
    to_add = mystring[prev_pos+len(prev_pattern)+1 : len(mystring)].strip()
    if prev_pattern in to_list:
        to_add = to_add.split()
    result[prev_pattern] = to_add
    return result

obtain_data(mystring, pattern, to_list)
```

This will return:

```
{'Foo-age': '50', 'Hop List': ['2', '4', '9', '0', '3'], 'Airplanes': ['12:1', '12:3', '12:4', '12:5'], 'Next Hop': 'LAX', 'Foo': 'Bar (Titi)', 'Origine ID': '49'}
```

I am first sorting the patterns into a list, according to where they appear on the string.

I am considering that there's ALWAYS a ':' right after the pattern. If that's not the case, it could prove to be way too hard to do this (considering there might be a pattern that is a prefix of another pattern, like the Foo and Foo-age you showed).

The other thing is: if you want one of the values to be a list, you have to specify what patterns will have their values turned into lists as a third parameter. If you don't think you will always do this, you can provide an empty set or just skip this, but I only followed what your example showed.

Final edit: In the case you will have patterns that might not appear on the code, you can just filter the result of the sorted list with a

```
ordered_pattern = filter(lambda x: mystring.find(x) != -1, ordered_pattern)
```

Right before the for loop

Hopefully this serves you well :)